# What is the difference between a figure environment compared to a figure* (figure star) environment

Tags: graphics, environments, starred-version

It is hard to search for this question since most search engines treat the `*` symbol somehow special, so sorry if that has been asked before.

So, basically, I just would like to know what the difference is between the following two latex snippets. The only difference is that one uses `figure` while to other one uses `figure*`:

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{MyFig}
    \caption{\label{fig:myfig}MyFig Caption.}
\end{figure*}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{MyFig}
    \caption{\label{fig:myfig}MyFig Caption.}
\end{figure}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `figure*` produces a double column figure in a two-column document.

Comment: Oh, thanks!
Since I have a single-column document, that explains why there was no visual difference...

Comment: Also, figure* doesn't support [h] or [b].

Comment: @IanThompson: Do you want to post an answer so this can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since the post has been unanswered for over 2 years, I am posting [Ian Thompsons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2417/ian-thompson) answer, so that this question can be marked as answered.

> `figure*` produces a double column figure in a two-column document.

> Also, `figure*` doesn't support `[h]` or `[b]`.

Comment: Using `stfloats.sty`, option `[b]` is working in `figure*`

Comment: Ok, so that's why I lose my shit every time I have to place a figure in two columns at the top or bottom of the page. This has been going on for like 10 years.

Comment: See also [`dblfloatfix`](https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/dblfloatfix/dblfloatfix.pdf) to place a `figure*` at the bottom.